# BigQuery GIS table to GeoJSON type Feature Collection with SQL and/or Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, google-bigquery, geojson, multilinestring

I have some BigQuery tables with spatial data (lon, lat, point, and linestring) representing boat tracks. 
I'm trying to get them into a GeoJSON for an API output. 
I have one method that uses Python to query my table into a pandas dataframe, which I can then use a function to create a feature collection.
But, there's so much data/day that it'd be ideal if I could perform some kind of efficient linestring union and simplify.

My current method:

```
# Query BigQuery table
sql = """SELECT 
    lon, lat, lead_lon, lead_lat, 
    CAST(CAST(timestamp AS DATE) as string) as date,
    UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp) as unix_secs,
    CAST(ship_num AS STRING) AS ship_num,
    op,
    CAST(knots AS FLOAT64) AS knots,
    point,
    linestring
    FROM `ship_segments`  
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2020-04-16' AND '2020-04-17';"""

# Make into pandas dataframe
df = client.query(sql).to_dataframe()

#df to geojson fn
def data2geojson(df):
        features = []
        insert_features = lambda X: features.append(
                geojson.Feature(geometry=geojson.LineString(([X["lead_lon"], X["lead_lat"], X["knots"], X["unix_secs"]],
                                                             [X["lon"], X["lat"], X["knots"], X["unix_secs"]])),
                                properties=dict(date=X["date"],
                                                mmsi=X["ship_num"],
                                                operator=X["op"]
                                                )))
        df.apply(insert_features, axis=1)

        geojson_obj = geojson.dumps(geojson.FeatureCollection(features, indent=2, sort_keys=True), sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
        return(geojson_obj)

results = data2geojson(df)
```

This returns a GeoJSON:

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-119.049945, 33.983277, 10.5502, 1587104709], [-119.034677, 33.975823, 10.5502, 1587104709]], "type": "LineString"}, "properties": {"date": "2020-04-17", "mmsi": "235098383", "operator": "Evergreen Marine Corp"}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-120.176933, 34.282107, 22.7005, 1587114969], [-120.144453, 34.275147, 22.7005, 1587114969]], "type": "LineString"}, "properties": {"date": "2020-04-17", "mmsi": "235098383", "operator": "Evergreen Marine Corp"}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-118.361737, 33.64647, 11.3283, 1587096305], [-118.356308, 33.643713, 11.3283, 1587096305]], "type": "LineString"}, "properties": {"date": "2020-04-17", "mmsi": "538005412", "operator": "Scorpio MR Pool Ltd"}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-118.414667, 33.673013, 12.7684, 1587097278], [-118.411707, 33.671493, 12.7684, 1587097278]], "type": "LineString"}, "properties": {"date": "2020-04-17", "mmsi": "538005412", "operator": "Scorpio MR Pool Ltd"}, "type": "Feature"}, {"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-119.377783, 34.062612, 10.5456, 1587102119], [-119.384212, 34.064217, 10.5456, 1587102119]], "type": "LineString"}, "properties": {"date": "2020-04-17", "mmsi": "636018225", "operator": "Ocean Network Express Pte Ltd"}, "type": "Feature"}], "indent": 2, "sort_keys": true, "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

But I'm trying something like:

```
select 
ship_num,
date(timestamp) as date,
AVG(speed_knots) as avg_speed_knots,
st_union_agg(linestring) as multiline
from(
SELECT 
  *,
  row_number() OVER w AS num,
  ST_GeogPoint(lon,lat) as geom,
  LEAD(ST_GeogPoint(lon,lat)) OVER w AS geom2,
  ST_MAKELINE((ST_GeogPoint(lon,lat)), (LEAD(ST_GeogPoint(lon,lat)) OVER w)) AS linestring,
  LEAD(STRING(timestamp), 0) OVER w AS t1, 
  LEAD(STRING(timestamp), 1) OVER w AS t2,
  FROM
  `ship_data`
  where timestamp >= '2020-04-10'
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY ship_num ORDER BY timestamp)) AS q
group by
ship_num, date(timestamp);
```

This gives me multilinestrings in a table, but then I need to simplify and get them in a GeoJSON FeatureCollection output.

Any ideas that don't use PostGIS?

Comment: Did you try `ST_ASGEOJSON`?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa yes, I tried st_asgeojson, but it turns each geog column into its own geojson. So then there's a table with a bunch of regular columns and a geojson column.
But, I can't figure out a way to go from a table with properties and geography to a proper GeoJSON FeatureCollection... at least on the BigQuery side of things.

Comment: Are you trying to make a union of your geometries into a single GeoJson?

Comment: @rmesteves Yes. I need a way to get the geographies and some of their other properties into a single GeoJSON FeatureCollection. 
That last query attempts to join the linestrings into multilinestrings, based on group by ship and date, which I would want in a single GeoJSON FeatureCollection.
Either way, I'm working on a way to get my BigQuery table data into a single geojson. 
see: https://geojson.org/ for the general output

Comment: Can you try using ST_ASGEOJSON( ST_UNION (your, geometries, ..))  ?

Comment: @rmesteves not bad! it gives a workable geojson with: 

```SELECT 
ST_ASGEOJSON( ST_UNION_AGG (linestring))
FROM `segments` ;```

But the trink is getting a FeatureCollection, so there's the geometry feature but also the properties associated with each geometry.

Comment: In PostGIS I'd use something like: 
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html
But BigQuery just started to support ST_ functions

Comment: In the documentation, we can find this: "BigQuery GIS supports only individual geometry objects in GeoJSON. BigQuery GIS does not currently support GeoJSON feature objects, feature collections, or the GeoJSON file format." 

Apparently its not possible 

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/gis-data#differences_between_wkt_and_geojson

Comment: @rmesteves, I did see that, which is why my question is titled, "BigQuery GIS table to GeoJSON type Feature Collection with SQL and/or Python." I guess I was trying to imply that I need an approach that uses sql and/or python to create a FeatureCollection, not just SQL.

Comment: What I would do is output BigQuery result as regular JSON (with geometry column and properties you want to put into Feature as other columns) and then convert the JSON to GeoJSON. It is very simple, see e.g. https://github.com/mentin/geoscripts/tree/master/bq2geojson